# How to parse json array in php

Tags: php, json

everyone. I am posting some JSON array data to my PHP file. But I am unable to parse that data.

What I have done till now:

I am posting data through `POST` method my data is like `["T-shirt","Shirt"]`

```
<?php
  $msg = $_POST['jsonarray'];
  //$msg = json_decode($msg,true); when i am making this line then all ok but how to parse i don't know
  $response["msg"] = $msg;
  echo json_encode($response);   
?>
```

When I am not making the line no.3 as comment i am getting `null` in `$msg`

So if anyone of you know so please help "How to parse json array in php"

Comment: Make `var_dump($_POST)` and see what is inside your request. Is `jsonarray` param exists? It contains string with valid json data?

Comment: imo, you are currently trying to encode JSON twice. i.e. $msg is JSON, then you put that JSON text in an array and encode it again? Is that what you want to do?

Comment: i am doing twice because i want to see what data i am sending actually i am having a array list in android program now i convert it in json arrray and trying to parse that data for further use.

Comment: It won't actually encode it twice. The second time it is just a string in an array? Actually, it will be interesting to see what the output actually is. Howver, I suspect, you will need to decode the $msg part in the array separately. Why are you doing this? It does seem quite involved.

Comment: Thank you Ryan Vincent for giving your precious time.Now i explain you what i want to do=>1)In android i am making cart of clothes for order.2)I am holding this cart in ArrayList.3)Now i want to send this ArrayList to my php file where i want to use this arrayList content to send to GCM cloud.

Comment: I hope now the things are clear.

Answer (score 1):

> parse data
>   echo json_encode($response);

If you want to parse you should be calling `json_decode()` NOT encode as you do now. Assuming `$_POST['jsonarray'];` really holds the string represeing JSON array it's all you need:

```
$a = '["T-shirt","Shirt"]';
var_dump(json_decode($a));
```

would return

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "T-shirt"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Shirt"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You maybe wanted to do the following:

```
foreach($user->data as $mydata)

    {
         echo $mydata->name . "\n";
         foreach($mydata->values as $values)
         {
              echo $values->value . "\n";
         }
    }
```

Comment: A random answer to a random question ? how is this relevant to OP's question ?